# Modify axes range using plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using the following code to generate a bubble plot using `plotly`:

```
Dataframe.iplot(kind='bubble', x='branch', y='retention', size='active_users', text='active_users',
             xTitle='', yTitle='Retention',
             filename='cufflinks/PlotName')
```

I'd like to set a manual range for Y axis.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go    
layout = go.Layout(
        yaxis=dict(
            range=[0, 0.4]
        )
    )

    Dataframe.iplot(kind='bubble', x='branch', y='retention', size='active_users', text='active_users',
                 xTitle='', yTitle='Retention',
                 filename='cufflinks/PlotName', layout = layout)
```

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 20):

A solution that works with subplots is:

```
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 0.4], row=1, col=1)
```

Comment: how do you set your fig?

Comment: oops. @EliBorodach, sorry for the delay. `ax, fig = plt.subplots(...)`