# Plotly bar charts: Wrong x-axis alignment of bars in facet/subplots

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, bar-chart, subplot, facet

I'm trying to create bar plots separated for subgroups using plotly, but running into problems if the amount of bars differ between subgroups. When using bar charts of ploty express, we have the problem that the x-Axis alignment in a facet with lesser bars looks off, because the space for the missing bar is still blocked.
Using plotly.graph_objects.Bar, the x-alignment seems okay until I want to adjust the width of bars to be slimmer. Then an ugly gap is showing, as I cannot set width or gap-size at the same time.

Here is some example data and code:

data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Facet':['A','A','B','B','B','B'],'ID':['01','01','02','02','03','03'],'Day':[0,3,0,3,0,3],'Val':[98,99,97,95,98,99]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Code for px:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df,x='Day',y='Val',color='ID',barmode='group',facet_col='Facet')
fig
```

Result px:
[Plotly express facetted bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxLs2.png)

Code using go:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
grouped=df.groupby('Facet',sort=False)
fig2 = make_subplots(rows=1,cols=grouped.ngroups)
for i, (name,group) in enumerate(grouped):
    for subname,subgroup in group.groupby('ID'):        
        fig2.add_trace(go.Bar(x=subgroup['Day'],y=subgroup['Val'],name=subname,width=0.5),row=1,col=i+1)

fig2.update_layout(barmode='group',bargroupgap=0)       
fig2
```

Result go:
[Plotly graph objects bar charts in subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W98pG.png)

I tried to fix it using alignmentgroup,offsetgroup but did not succeed. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898483/modify-axes-range-using-plotly) or just using `fig.update_xaxes(range=[min_range, max_range])` can help you.

Comment: Hi Giovanni, thank you for your answer, but the axis-range is not the problem here.